# NLSSORT like operation not working for single character wildcard

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to make NLSSORT work with single character wildcard.

```
create table alex_test(col1 varchar2(20))
insert into alex_test values('test')
insert into alex_test values('fast')    
select col1 from alex_test where col1 like '__st'
select col1 from alex_test where col1 like '__' || 'st'
```

The above statements insert 'test' and 'fast', and both select statements return both rows.

```
select col1 from alex_test where NLSSORT(col1, 'NLS_SORT=generic_m_ai') like '%' || NLSSORT('st', 'NLS_SORT=generic_m_ai')
```

The statement above also returns both rows.

However these two statements do not return the rows:

```
select col1 from alex_test where NLSSORT(col1, 'NLS_SORT=generic_m_ai') like '__' || NLSSORT('st', 'NLS_SORT=generic_m_ai')
select col1 from alex_test where NLSSORT(col1, 'NLS_SORT=generic_m_ai') like NLSSORT('__st', 'NLS_SORT=generic_m_ai')
```

Is there a way to make it work somehow? It seems odd that matching multiple characters with '%' works, but matching single character with '_' does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you expect. Maybe if you tell us what you are trying to achieve we could help. Right now it seems you're using the wrong function for the wrong job.

[`NLSSORT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions113.htm#i78399) should be used exclusively for sorting, i-e in the `ORDER BY` clause. It returns `RAW` (binary) data that doesn't play nicely with `VARCHAR2`. When you concatenate a `raw` and a `varchar2`, the raw will be converted to its hexadecimal value and the whole string will be traited as a `varchar2`.

It happens that "test" and "fast" have the same ending while applying `NLSSORT`, but I don't see how you can be sure of the number of bytes each character will be converted to.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have bytes represented as Strings, you may use 8 underscores instead of 2 (depends on the language).

@Vincent, I think you confusing NLSSORT with parameter NLS_SORT.

Comment: From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions113.htm#i78399) _"NLSSORT returns the string of bytes used to sort char."_

Comment: So, you can use nlssort anywhere you need to compare. As used in the where clause comparison example in the docs link you have provided. Not necessarily the order-by clause. Yes, I accept "like" doesn't seem to be a good candidate of doing what Alex is doing.